# How do I invoke copy constructor appropriately while using rvalue for an object?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, rvalue

Here I am trying to push an object into a vector using push_back function and rvalue of that object. Look at the `addMovie()` function of the `Movies` class below

```
#include "Movies.h"

void Movies::addMovie(std::string name, std::string rating, int watched)
{

    movieColl.push_back(Movie{name,rating,watched});           //apparently I am having problem here

}
```

Rest of the required parts are here

```
class Movies
{
    public:
        void addMovie(std::string name, std::string rating, int watched);

    protected:

    private:
        std::vector <Movie> movieColl;

};
```

Movie class itself... I have just showed constructors here although I have implemented the other functions

```
class Movie
{
    public:
        Movie(std::string name,std::string rating, int watched = 0);
        Movie(const Movie &obj);

        Movie();

        void getMovieDetails();
        void addToWatchTime(int num = 1);
        void setMovieDetails(std::string name,std::string rating, int watched = 0);

    protected:

    private:
        std::string name;
        std::string rating;
        int watched;
};

Movie::Movie(std::string name,std::string rating, int watched):name{name},rating{rating},watched{watched}
{
    //ctor

}

Movie::Movie(const Movie &obj):Movie(obj.name,obj.rating,obj.watched){}

Movie::Movie():Movie("None","NA",0){}
```

My MAIN Function

```
#include<iostream>

#include"Movies.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{


    Movies collection;

    collection.addMovie("GG","PG",343);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem currently?

Comment: With the code you show, you don't need an explicit copy-constructor. You could rely on the default automatically generated copy-constructor to do the right thing (following [the rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero)).

Comment: use `emplace_back` as it uses rvalue ref.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are right...

Comment: @NutCracker well the problem was that my debugger was giving off an error, along the lines of "Failed to open file ../../../../sjlj.c" when executing the line in question. The problem is solved for now following Someprogrammerdude advice

Answer (score 0):

Basically there's two approach to solve this problem

Approach 1: Use default copy constructor provided by compiler.

Approach 2: This ones a bit weird. So instead of typing

```
movieColl.push_back(Movie{name,rating,watched});
```

I typed

```
movieColl.push_back(Movie(name,rating,watched));
```

Basically I changed the curlys to normal parentheses and it worked..

Comment: And what was this advice?

Comment: Just using the default copy constructor

Comment: I meant for you to put that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use emplace_back and std::move.

```
movieColl.emplace_back(std::move(Movie{name,rating,watched}));
```